# Map as a global variable in Ocaml

Tags: dictionary, global-variables, ocaml

I have a question about manipulating a map as a global variable. In the beginning of my file, I have:

```
module IntOrd = struct type t = int let compare = ( - ) end
module IntMap = Map.Make( IntOrd )
```

Then I want to declare a global variable by `let variables = IntMap.empty`, then `variables` will be modified in some functions in this file. For instance, in a function `let analyze (p: s_program) : unit =` I want to fill in `variables` with some values in `p`. But I don't see how to do it, because it seems that I could not modify `variables` anymore; `IntMap.add : key -> 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t` would not work either because it does not change directly the values.

Do I have to make this global variable as a reference?

Could anyone help? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you kind of answered your own question :). You want it to be a *variable*. Ocaml is functional, `let x = ...` does not declare a variable (it's a constant binding); to get a variable you need to make a reference. And then indeed you can modify it in your functions as in:

```
variables := IntMap.add foo bar !variables
```

Comment: and pls don't assume my answer is evil just because of my reputation ;)

Comment: well... you and @sepp2k both answered my question, as you may need this credit to build up your reputation... i set your answer as accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to be able to modify the map, you'll have to make it a reference. Then you can change it using `variables := IntMap.add foo bar !variables`.